# .NET WinForms - application which is not dependent to .NET Framework?

Tags: winforms, installation

Is it possible to develop a WinForms application which when deployed (of course on Windows) will not be dependent to .NET Framework? And How?

Okay, put it this way, I want all the dll's and stuffs to be included in my application, so when installed in a machine, the users don't have to install .NET Framework, something like that. Is it possible?

Comment: Not really a duplicate - this question is not about removing the dependency to the .NET framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. You can however include the .NET client installer into the installer for your application:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24872

There is an article on MSDN about redistribution of the .NET framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994395.aspx

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll just stick to .NET-dependent app, it has a lot of advantages.